# JSON ObjectMapper in Spring - how to map JSON to three class?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a JSON file:

```
{
  "a": "content",
  "b": "content",
  "c": "content",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "a": "content",
      "b": "content"
    }
  ],
  "parameters2": [
    {
      "a": "content"
    },
    {
      "b": "content"
    }
  ]
}
```

and model class :
First.java

```
@Id
    @Column(name="a")
    String a;

    @Column(name="b")
    String b;

    @Column(c= "c")
    String author;

    @OneToMany
    List<Parameters> parameters = new LinkedList<>();

    @OneToMany
    List<Parameters2> parameters2= new LinkedList<>();
```

and two parameters class as like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Parameters{

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(name = "a")
    String a;
}
```

I would like to map my JSON with ObjectMapper.
"a": "content",
  "b": "content",
  "c": "content" I would like to map to FirstClass.java but parameteters and parameters2 arrays to two other class.
How can I do this?
Now i try `firstClass = mapper.readValue(manifestJSON, FirstClass.class);` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First class should be

```
@Id
@Column(name="a")
String a;

@Column(name="b")
String b;

List<Parameter1> parameters;

List<Parameter2> parameters2;
```

And your `Parameter1` will be like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Long id
@Column(name="a")
String a;

@Column(name="b")
String b;
```

And parameter2 class will be like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Parameters{

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(name = "a")
    String a;
}
```